# Copied array is being affected by changing the original array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

In **jupyter notebook** with  **python**  when i am changing the array value which is copy of the other array, it will affect on original array to.which is not convenient to use for me.

The below code i've tried on my jupyter notebook and i am changing the value of  **arr_temp[1]**  array.But it will affect to the  **original numpy array** .

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,5,6,7,8,94])
array[4:6]
arr_temp = array[4:6]
arr_temp[1]=100
array
```

I expect `array([ 1,  5,  6,  7,  8, 94])` but i got values are `array([  1,   5,   6,   7,   8, 100])`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `arr_temp = array[4:6].copy()`.
You should always use copy() when you want to make changes to a subset of your data, otherwise python will see it as a slice and change the new and the original object.